# on server that implements the node js architecture, what all the other threads used for?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So we have Single Thread which is used to handles client requests.
But a serious server has a lot of processors and therefore also a lot of cores.
So let's say there is one thread serving clients, what are all the other threads doing?
They execute the user requests in the background and after they are ready they forward them to
the "Event Queue"?

Answer (score 0):

A server usually has an operating system which manages resource usage.
Most OS are capable of running multiple applications at a time. Therefore other applications may use the unused resources.

If, and only if your server has no other applications running except your NodeJS application theoretically only one CPU thread will be used and all others will idle.

PS: NodeJS also offers Workers

> The node:worker_threads module enables the use of threads that execute JavaScript in parallel.

https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker-threads

Comment: But it doesn't make sense, it's a waste of resources, It is true that there are always processes running in the background related to the operating system and all, let's assume for a second that it doesn't exist, When a client requests, for example, information from the DB, are the other threads actually pulling the information?
or does the main thread do everything? (including gets the information from the database)
(without using "Workers")

Comment: Highly depends on the driver you're using. Some might use native extensions which might dedicate work away from the main thread but if not, yes you will not use the full extend of available resources.